# Will a Group always have subgroup?

Tags: group-theory

If there is a group of order P, where P is not prime, will there be atleast one subgroup always? If yes, can it be proven? I just started group theory. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say the order of the group was $n=ab$ with $a,b>1$.  Pick $g\in G$ with $g\neq e$.  If $<g> \neq G$ then we're done. Otherwise  $g$ has order $ab$ and $<g^a>$ works.

Comment: Thanks. I can now prove group of prime order is cyclic.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will have a non trivial subgroup if its order is not a prime and if it is not trivial. Google Sylow theorems.

Comment: Sylow theorems are overkill for this question.

Answer (score 0):

A group $G$ has the trivial subgroup $\{e\}$ and the whole group $G$ as subgroups ; one can refine the question to as whether a group $G$ always has a proper non trivial subgroup. And here $(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z},+)$ where $p$ is a prime is an example of group that has no proper non trivial subgroup.

Now if the order is not a prime first Sylow theorem tells us that if the order of $G$ is $p^n\cdot s$ where $s$ is not divisible by $p$, then there exists a subgroup $H$ of $G$ whose order is $p^n$.